# Arithmetic Progression-Question

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sum of $n$ terms of an A.P. is $2n+3n^2$

Find the $r^{th}$ term.

TRIED ANSWER:

Sum of $n$ terms $(Sn)=3n^2+2n$  ............$(I)$

$Sn=\frac{n(2a+(n-1)d)}{2}$ $.............(from formula)$

$=2an+dn^2-dn$                        ............$(II)$

$\Rightarrow\frac{(2a-d)+dn}{2} = 2+3n$               ------ [from(I)&(II)]

By comparison,

$d=6$

$a=5$ $.............(III)$

*The answer given in the $Solutions$ is $6r-1$*.

Comment: By comparison $d/2=3$

Comment: You missed a division by $2$ in $(II)$

Comment: Ah yes i forgot it.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $r-th$ term is: $a_r = a_1 + (r-1)d = 5 + 6(r-1) = 6r - 1$. Your mistake is $d = 3$ while it is $6$ in step II.

Comment: Thanks a lot..... I see where i've mistaken!!

Answer (score 0):

Another way :
$$T_r=S_r-S_{r-1}=2r+3r^2-\{2(r-1)+3(r-1)^2\}$$
$$=2\{r-(r-1)\}+3\{r^2-(r-1)^2\}=2+3(2r-1)$$