# If the sum of $n$ terms of an A.P. is $2n+3n^2$, find the $r^{th}$ term.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

If the sum of $n$ terms of an Arithmetic Progression is $2n+3n^2$, find the $r^{th}$ term.

Note: This question is from the book  *Higher Algebra* by H.S. Hall & S.R. Knight and its answer is $6r-1$. (As listed at the end of the book).

What I've already done:
$$
S_n = 2n+3n^2\\
S_n = \frac{n}{2}\left \{ 2a+(n-1)d \right \}\\2n+3n^2=\frac{n}{2}\left \{ 2a+(n-1)d \right \}
$$

Comment: This question is also there in Class 11 mathematics textbook by RS Aggarwal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arithmetic Progression-Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/818963/arithmetic-progression-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that the sum of the first $n$ terms is $S_n = 2n + 3n^2$, so the sum of the first $(n - 1)$ terms is $S_{n-1} = 2(n - 1) + 3(n - 1)^2$. But if the $n$th term is $t_n$, then recall that $S_{n-1} + t_n = S_n$. Hence, it follows that:
\begin{align*}
t_n
&= S_n - S_{n-1} \\
&= (2n + 3n^2) - (2(n - 1) + 3(n - 1)^2) \\
&= (2n + 3n^2) - (2n - 2 + 3(n^2 - 2n + 1)) \\
&= (2n + 3n^2) - (2n - 2 + 3n^2 - 6n + 3) \\
&= (2n + 3n^2) - (3n^2 - 4n + 1) \\
&= 6n - 1 \\
\end{align*}
as desired.

---

**Remark:** Notice that the formula for $S_n$ gives us a **lot** of information. Indeed, we didn't need to know that the sequence was an arithmetic progression, and we didn't need to memorize any fancy formulas.

Comment: Wow, that was awesome. Never looked at it that way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is problem number 17 from page 35, Examples IV. b.

The original solution of this problem from page 10 of [Solutions of the Examples in Higher Algebra (LaTeX Edition)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/150876350X) by Hall and Knight is [image]

Comment: http://www.amazon.in/dp/150876350X

Comment: The original _Solutions of the Examples in Higher Algebra_ is available from the Internet Archive in a variety of formats. [See here](https://archive.org/details/cu31924105225399).