# Suppose $S_n=2n+3n^2$. What is the $r$th term?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic-progressions

For every $n$ the sum of the first $n$ terms of an [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) is $2n+3n^2$. What is the $r$th term of the sequence in terms of $r$.

Comment: Can you find the term ($r=1$) of the sequence? Now using what you find and the sum of the first $2$ terms, can you find the 2nd term? Can you generalize this to find the 3rd term? Basically $a_r=S_r-S_{r-1}$.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by that

Comment: I don't understand your comment either: The question asks you to find "what is the rth term of the sequence in terms of r" and I simply asked you what the *first* term of the sequence is.

Comment: oh, the first term is 5 right?

Comment: Correct. (How did you find it?) Now can you find the 2nd term?

Comment: oh so the 2nd term is $4+12-(5)=11$ so $d=6$

Comment: @Jack does Leonard Euler solution actually work or is it just coincidental

Comment: Wouldn't it be more interesting if you can figure it out on your own? (The answer actually has been given out in the first comment.) So the next step is to find the 3rd term. Can you do that?

Comment: 17, so it goes up by 6 every time and the first term is 5 so the equation is $a_n=5+6(n-1)$ right

Comment: the common difference

Comment: You got the correct answer using also the fact that the sequence forms an arithmetic progression. Actually, you don't need it.

Comment: what'd you mean

Comment: I mean you can find out the 3rd term (and likewise the nth term) *without* using $d=6$.

Comment: I know, as the sum of the 3rd term-(1st and 2nd term)

Comment: But this is the "(the sum of the first 3 terms) - (the sum of the first 2 terms)", isn't it? You don't need to use $d=6$ here. Likewise, you can find the **4**th term by "(the sum of the first **4** terms) - (the sum of the first **3** terms)", so on and so forth.

Comment: ya the sum of the (first $r$ terms)-(the sum of $r-1$ terms) right?

Comment: Now you got it.

Comment: oooo now Euler's whole solution kind of makes sense. But I have a question are you allowed to just input $r-1$ into the equation cuz that seems too good to be true

Comment: $n$ is a "dummy" variable in the expression of $S_n$. One could replace with any positive integers, including $r-1$, of course.

Comment: im not very good at function notation. But thanks you really taught me more than an answer but instead an approach. Thank you very much :)

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If the sum of $n$ terms of an A.P. is $2n+3n^2$, find the $r^{th}$ term.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1165898/if-the-sum-of-n-terms-of-an-a-p-is-2n3n2-find-the-rth-term)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A clever solution will be to notice the $rth$ term is $S_r-S_{r-1}$ using the equation...

$(3r^2+2r)-(3(r-1)^2+2(r-1))=6r-1$

Thus $$6r-1$$
is the desired equation.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of first $n$ terms of series is $$S_n=2n+3n^2$$ 
The sum of first $n-1$ terms of series is $$S_{n-1}=2(n-1)+3(n-1)^2$$
$$S_{n-1}=3n^2-4n+1$$
 Hence the $n$th term of the given series, 
$$T_n=S_n-S_{n-1}$$
$$=2n+3n^2-(3n^2-4n+1)$$
$$=6n-1$$
hence $r$th term of given series, $$T_r=6r-1$$
Above term shows that it is an Arithmetic Progression

Comment: that's the same thing as The Art of problem solving solution

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Use $S_n$ to find $S_1$ and $ S_2$.

We know that $S_1 = a_1$ and $ S_2 - S_1 = a_2$